# Youtube package not working in flutter. just keep getting the loading screen

Tags: flutter, youtube-player-flutter

Youtube package not working in flutter.
just keep getting the loading screen.
this is loading screen.

[image]

this is my code.

```
 youtubeContainer(int count) {
return List.generate(count, (index) {
  final YoutubePlayerController _controller = YoutubePlayerController(
      initialVideoId: youtubeList[index],
      flags: const YoutubePlayerFlags(
        autoPlay: false,
        
        mute: false,
        loop: false,
      ));
  return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: YoutubePlayer(
              controller: _controller,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
              liveUIColor: Colors.red,
              showVideoProgressIndicator: true,
              
              progressColors: const ProgressBarColors(
                playedColor: Colors.red,
              ),
            )),
      ]);
});
```

}

I got data from FirebaseDatabase. and then I used Gridview.count.
Why does it keep showing loading?

Comment: I found the cause. If you give width and height values, youtubePlayer does not work.
Do you know how to make it play by giving width and height values?

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<String> videosList = <String>[
    "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BBAyRBTfsOU",
    "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PCwL3-hkKrg",
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: GridView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: videosList.length,
          gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: 2,
            childAspectRatio: 16 / 9,
          ),
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            final YoutubePlayerController controller = YoutubePlayerController(
              initialVideoId: YoutubePlayer.convertUrlToId(
                    videosList[index],
                  ) ??
                  "",
              flags: const YoutubePlayerFlags(autoPlay: false),
            );
            return YoutubePlayer(
              controller: controller,
              // showVideoProgressIndicator: true,
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Proof: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wr1dF.png

Package: https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_player_flutter (youtube_player_flutter: ^8.1.1)

Comment: I found the cause. If you give width and height values, youtubePlayer does not work.
Do you know how to make it play by giving width and height values?

Comment: I don't get any of these issues. I just tested the code. I fit the sized box & container as a parent of the youtube widget, and I wrote the width property in the Youtube player, but it does not affect the loading scenario. Could you give me your Youtube player package version?

Comment: my youtubeplayer version is youtube_player_flutter: ^8.1.1